# Is there any way to pause cutscenes in Mortal Kombat 9?

Tags: mortal-kombat-9

I've been having a blast playing through Mortal Kombat's story mode. However, I often find myself needing to pause the cutscene I am currently viewing and have yet to find a way of doing so. My current "solution" is alt-tabbing and killing the game before the cutscene plays through, but that is hardly convenient (nor is it actually pausing).

I am playing on a PC, in case that matters.

Comment: You could possibly try taking a screenshot. Or recording the game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pause cutscenes, but you can replay the last one if you quit to the menu before the fight ends and the resume Story mode

Answer (score 1):

I'm on ps4 and pressing the options button pauses the cutscene and gives me a menu with skip being on the list I realize your on pc but if it's possible on ps4 maybe there's a way to do it on pc